# I can't move objects with the mouse

Tags: transforms

Somehow I've ended up not being able to move objects with my mouse the way I expect. In some cases they will move, but only by grid lines. I also can't rotate. I can still move them by typing a value into the move dialog, but rotating doesn't work at all.

Here is the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/17CQTB_8dIWrEcy0Uf-8vGA3XPBsJI6WE/view?usp=sharing

Ay ideas about how to get back to freeform movement?

Comment: disable the Snapping option (magnet icon on the top)

Answer (score 2):

Disable "Affect only locations":

[image]

Comment: The solution was a combination of the comment about snapping and disabling this option