# Bone wont rotate freely anymore

Tags: bones, transforms

I am hoping someone can answer this. My bones rotated just fine at first. I animated thirty or so frames. suddenly, they won't rotate at all. They are not locked and if I copy and paste the one model into a fresh Blender file it seems to work fine. the file isn't very big so I'm confused. thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: update: when I copy and paste all objects into new blender file, the bone movement is back. so something happened to my file. maybe I hit a hotkey or something. starting from a new blend file is not always easy, so I'd like to know how to prevent this thing in the future. thanks in advance!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't move objects with the mouse](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/202683/i-cant-move-objects-with-the-mouse)

Comment: For questions like this it's best to include a screenshot showing all the widgets and gizmos so we can see what is turned on.